# Issue while installing Pods (GRPC)

Tags: ios

I have been trying to install pods, everything is working fine until it reaches "Installing BoringSSL-GRPC" after this point nothing is reflected back everything stops there and it is still installing. Is there any way to skip or make it go the same speed as that of other installations?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check which pod has dependency of the GRPC, replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing the pods but that was not going as it was creating problems with code so I removed all the pods and install all of them one after another. Though it took alot of to install grpc and follwing installations but it was all completed successfully. Hope it can help you.